# $stmt->error doesn't show, but query does nothing

Tags: php

Another problem...

I wanna update something in my database, this time it's the name of the slider I'm using, so I'm doing this:

```
public function changeSlider($name) {
$errorsslide = array();
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE cms_functions  SET value = ? WHERE title='Slider' ");
if ( false===$stmt ) {
    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
if ( false===$stmt ) {
     die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmt->error();
$stmt->close();
$errorsslide[] = "<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button><strong>Success!</strong> Slider Changed successfully!</div>";
return $errorsslide;
}
```

When I run the code it doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't update my DB neither...

Any answers?

Lisa

Comment: Where is your connection string ?

Comment: It's in the beginning of the file.

Comment: Try to put your connection string inside the function and run it again.

Comment: Where are you setting $this->mysqli?, it may be worth posting up the code for the class.

Comment: @JackFrankland Database class, but the rest works so, it can't be the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If the execute method does fail for whatever reason, you are not currently catching it correctly. You need to compare the return value of the method to see if it's false:

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ( false===$result ) {
     die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
```

I'm not sure the following line `$stmt->error();` is necessary too.

Where are you declaring the $mysqli instance? If it's in the function, and you have hidden it, that is fine. But if it's a property of the class, then you need to reference it like this everywhere you have included it:

```
$this->$mysqli
```